# Prevent installing passbook on multiple devices

Tags: ios, ios6, passbook

Not exactly a programming question but here it goes:

How can a company who is distributing passbook passes via email or web prevent a pass from being installed on more than one device?

I can not find anything about this on Apple docs. The only I can think of is to check on the device registration webservice whether the combination of pass type and serial has a device already registered and delete it , but I am not aware of any command to delete the pass remotely.

Another option would be to check if it is already registered prior to generating the pass but this would only work for URL distribution, not for email.

Is there any way to delete a pass remotely via push notification + update? Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mail and Mobile Safari will present any pass they are given and the user can decide to add them to their Passbook. There is nothing the pass creator can do to prevent it except to be careful about how the .pkpass files get handed around.

If you really only want to deliver a specific pass to a specific device you might consider a companion app that uses a custom API to communicate with the the backend and request the pass for that device that way. Then you have much more control than distribution via email or url links.

Apple frowns on trying to delete a pass programmatically; only users are supposed to delete passes because they added them. You can, however, update a pass to make it clear that is not valid and should be deleted. For example you can remove the bar code, if any, and use a background image with a big red "INVALID" on it.

Comment: I also thought about updating the pass to show it's invalid but that would update both passes: The original/legit one and the redistributed ones.
I will go for the option of pre checking if the pass type and serial combination has a registered device and show some error.
Thanks ;-)

Comment: Remember, 'updating' a pass only happens in the context of a single device requesting the update. You tell that device that that pass has changed and send it the updated pass. That in no way changes all the other passes out there, in particular, the original one that you do not report as needing updating. You still need some fancy footwork on the server side to make this work. Please don't forget the green check for this answer if your thanks extend that far.

Comment: Good point, but too much work just to get this behavior. I'll just check before the creation of the pass. (BTW, lovin the "if your thanks extend that far" lol ;-))

Answer (score 0):

Just to extend @ohmi's answer:

1. You cannot prevent passes from being installed on more than one
   device - e.g. if user enables iCloud for Passbook, the passes will get
   synced automatically across devices.
2. Considering your links to pkpasses are public, you may want to consider
   introducing one-time download links, but while it can fill your
   needs just fine, users can be really disappointed if it's impossible to re-add
   passes that they manually deleted. So I wouldn't recommend such solution.
3. You can make you pkpass links kind of private, so only GET request originating from your application and carrying a specific value for specific header field (e.g. auth_token),  will receive a pkpass file, however this way you almost disable pass distribution via email or via sharing URLs to passes and make pass updating probably impossible.